# A typo in Proposition 2.2, Eisenbud commutative algebra?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

I am trying to understand the formulation of Proposition 2.2 in Eisenbud's "Commutative algebra with the view...". Here is the place that is not clear to me

**Proposition 2.2.** Let $\varphi: R\to R[U^{-1}]$ be the natural map $r\to r/1$.

*a.* For any ideal $I\subset R[U^{-1} ]$ we have $I=\varphi^{-1}(I)R[U^{-1}]$. ...

Do I understand correctly that instead of $I=\varphi^{-1}(I)R[U^{-1}]$ we should have $I=\varphi^{-1}(I)[U^{-1}]$? Namely that we localize $\varphi^{-1}(I)$ at $U$? If my interpretation is wrong, how am I supposed to understand the notation $\varphi^{-1}(I)R[U^{-1}]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am unfamiliar with Eisenbud's book.

The ring $R[U^{-1}]$ can be naturally viewed as an $R$ module: you can define $s\frac{a}{b}$ as $\frac{s}{1}\frac{a}{b}$, which is the same as $\varphi(s)\frac{a}{b}$. Now remember that for any morphism $f: R\to S$ and any ideals $I\subset R$, $J\subset S$ we have ideals $f^{-1}(J)\subset R$ (contraction) and $f(I)S\subset S$ (extension).

What Eisenbud seems to be saying is that $I$ coincides with the extension of its contraction, which shows that any ideal of the localized ring is an extension of some ideal of the original ring.

But you are also not wrong: this extension coincides with the localization of the ideal. If you have access to Atiyah's Commutative Algebra, you can look up Proposition 3.11 and the text just preceding it.

Comment: Serge, thanks for this answer! I have Atiyah and Eisenbud of course says what Atiyah is saying. I guess, my problem is that of syntax. How do I read the expression $\varphi^{-1}(I) R[U^{-1}]$? For example $\varphi^{-1}(I)$ is an ideal in $R$. What does it mean when we write the localised  $R[U^{-1}]$ after $\varphi^{-1}(I)$? Note of course that  $\varphi^{-1}(I) R[U^{-1}]$ is supposed to be interpreted as an ideal in $R[U^{-1}]$, since it is stated to be equal to $I$ which is an ideal in $R[U^{-1}]$...

Comment: This means that you take all elements of $R[U^-1]$ and multiply them on the left by the elements of $\phi^{-1}(I)$. This is an instance of the general notation $IM$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $M$ is a left $R$-module, and then $IM$ is a submodule of $M$ generated by all products $im,\ i\in I, \ m\in M. $